# How do I echo a / (slash) in PHP?

Tags: php, echo

How do I echo a forwardslash `/`?

```
echo <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?> . '/directory/';
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you echo a forward slash is like this:

```
echo "/";
```

I think your problem is that you're opening/closing PHP tags inside what I assume is already a block of php. Change to this:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/directory/';
```

Comment: wow, I think I need to hang it up for the day if that's what I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . '/directory/';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're putting in extra `<?php` tags, which you don't need.

```
<?php

// Insert other PHP code here

echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/directory/';

// Insert more PHP code here

?> <!-- You can put HTML here -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya, you've closed your PHP tag while still using PHP.  Try this:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/directory/'; ?>
```

With regard to echoing a forward slash, no escape is necessary:

```
<?php echo "/"; ?>
```